# Why does the Transcript and the actual chat room have different Timestamps?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, chat-transcript

See the [transcript here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/797780#797780):

[image: hmmmmm]

And the [actual timestamps here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3w50.png):

[image: odd...]

Why do they differ?

For one thing the transcript version is in 12 Hour and and the chatroom is in 24 Hour mode.
And the other is that the transcript is **5 hours** ahead of the chatroom.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 9):

The transcript isn't 5 hours ahead of the chatroom, your timezone is 5 hours behind the UTC timestamps that all of Stack Exchange uses, including chat transcripts. Chat messages can be displayed in your timezone because chat uses Javascript to calculate the time difference between your system time and the server's time, and adjusts the time of incoming messages

Comment: Ok what about the 12HR vs 24HR formats?

Comment: It is most likely a usability thing.  When the chatroom is live, you obviously know if it is light or dark out.  But if you are looking at the transcript from a month ago, corrected to GMT, having the 24 hour format is better.

Comment: @amanaP: Not everyone around the world uses 12HR format.

Comment: Oy... but the 12hr stamps are on the UTC timestamps, not on the local timestamps....

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Oh, they are. I have no idea then; I suspect they did it accidentally

Answer (score 1):

The transcript is in GMT, and you must be have a local time that is 5 hours different.  Which would make sence since EST happens to be -5 hours.

Comment: Ok what about the 12HR vs 24HR formats?