# Localize transcript timestamps

Tags: feature-request, chat

When in chat, time is displayed in a localized format. This is nice - I know what time it is where I am.  When looking at transcripts, though, the site displays them in system time. This is not very nice - math is hard. Seemingly every other timestamp on the SE network is displayed localized, I would love it if transcripts were too.

I understand that it displays a "quick jump" list to jump to any part of that day's transcript (in system time). It may be a bit tricky to implement that in a clean way, but even just localizing that and having it "wrap around" midnight I think would be more friendly than not localizing transcripts at all.

[image: Transcripts not localized]

Comment: Related question - [Why does the Transcript and the actual chat room have different Timestamps?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116176/why-does-the-transcript-and-the-actual-chat-room-have-different-timestamps)

Comment: "Seemingly every other timestamp on the SE network is displayed localized" -- uhm, no. *Only* the in-chat timestamps are, and the event dates on chat room schedule pages.

Comment: @balpha I had thought that the displayed timestamps on questions and answers were too and their tooltips were displayed in system time. Looking at it, though, you seem to be right - both are system time. Even still, the discrepancy in chat timestamps is inconsistent at best.